# What is the quickest and easiest way to just build a email html page? and subscribe page?

Tags: css, web-applications, xhtml, web

We just want to build a very quick webpage that has two pages. One page where there is a form where a user can fill out a form and email us. Another page for users to put in their email address to subscribe to our newsletter.

What is the quickest way to build this? We are familiar with most web app technologies (asp, php, jsp, perl etc) but it seems such overkill to actually build a web app and database etc just to do this. Is there some prepackaged software or libraries or components that does just this?

Comment: Since this will involve server-side code, you should state your server OS/language preference.

Comment: You say that you don't want to go through the trouble of creating a database, but wouldn't you need one anyways to store the e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP mail() function to send email to yourself.